# Zoom Web SDK shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, html, zoom-sdk

I have tried to implement the CDN Client View according to the documentation ([link](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/build/#install-from-cdn)).

```
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/lib/vendor/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/lib/vendor/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/lib/vendor/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/lib/vendor/redux-thunk.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/lib/vendor/lodash.min.js"></script>

<!-- CDN for client view -->
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://source.zoom.us/2.1.0/css/react-select.css" />
</head>

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script/meeting.js') }}"></script>
```

But, while loading the page, I am getting the following error:

```
zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append')
    at s (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:1403948)
    at c (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:1404060)
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:17201)
    at n (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:111)
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:535046)
    at n (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:111)
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:2272)
    at n (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:111)
    at Object.<anonymous> (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:36714)
    at n (zoom-meeting-2.1.0.min.js:2:111)
```

[image: error]

I have also tried with meeting versions 2.9.7 and 2.9.5 but got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a body tag in your HTML file.